# C++ Erase-remove Idiom on non-existant value in vector

Tags: c++, c++17, erase-remove-idiom

I want to remove an element from a vector, but it is not guaranteed that the element exists.
I have looked online but found no information regarding how the erase-remove idiom would treat a value that isn't in the container.

My vector is declared as such: (with the members being added/modified in other pars of the code)

```
std::vector<Person*> _members
```

I want to create a remove method inside a class Group containing _members as an attribute to attempt removal of a given person from the group.

I currently am going with: (where person to remove is a pointer to a Person object)

```
_members.erase(std::remove(_members.begin(), _members.end(), person_to_remove), _members.end());
```

How will this handle attempting to remove a Person which is not in the vector ? Ideally I would also like to return a boolean to confirm whether the removal has been successful or not, is there a way to do so with my current implementation ?

Comment: The `remove` call returns an iterator to the first element that matches the value to be removed. If there is no such value, it will return `_members.end()`, and then the call to `erase` will erase no elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How will this handle attempting to remove a Person which is not in the vector ?

Erase-Remove idiom handles correctly non present element (and also multiple elements).

> Ideally I would also like to return a boolean to confirm whether the removal has been successful or not, is there a way to do so with my current implementation?

You might compare size before and after the removal:

```
const auto old_size = _members.size();
_members.erase(std::remove(_members.begin(), _members.end(), person_to_remove),
               _members.end());
const bool deleted = old_size != _members.size();
```

Comment: So it just deletes it if it finds it and (?) does nothing if the element is not present ? I am curious to know how it handles it concretely.

Comment: *"Basically"*, `std::remove` moves element to delete at the end, then we erase the (potentially empty) range of deleted elements.

Comment: So here nothing would be moved right ? Or would it therefore be more efficient to first check if it exists and then only delete it if it does ?

Comment: If no element would be removed, then nothing is moved, and erase does nothing. The 2 option are linear and similar.

Comment: Coming back to this I am wondering: what if the vector was empty and we tried to remove something from it ? Would there need to be some specific sort of check first ?

Comment: `std::remove` will iterate empty range and return `end()` as no elements to erase. Then `erase` will delete empty range (so no-op) from empty range. All is fine.